# How to run a html file (which is having external js file) through nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I want to run index.html file (in which external js file client.js is included) through nodejs

Here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> WEBCAM </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id='request'>Request Camera</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my server code which i am making to run this file through nodejs

```
var http= require('http');
var fs= require('fs');
var file= fs.readFile("./public/index.html", function(error,html) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  } else {
    var server= http.createServer(function(req,rspn) {
      rspn.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
      rspn.write(html);
      rspn.end();
    });
    server.listen(8000);
  }
});
```

If i copy the external js file directly into html file and run it through nodejs , then it is working properly but not if i make the js file as an external file.
My external file(client.js) is following -

```
function requestVideo() {       
  if (hasGetUserMedia()) {                
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true,audio:false}, function(localMediaStream) {       
      reqBtn.style.display = 'none';        
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);        
      startBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');        
    },errorCallback);       }       
    else{        
      alert("getUserMedia() is not supported in your system");       
    }      
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run HTML file"?

Comment: Your server only serves the HTML file, not the JS file, so how is the client supposed to get the JS file?

Comment: I am running server.js using node to run the server code. Now after I am opening html file in localhost:8000 then html file is not including the client.js file instead it is copying the same content of index.html in client.js also

Comment: @tkausl In my html file i am including client.js file 
<script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script> and trying to load the content from client.js but it is not happening

Comment: Yes, because your node.js server doesn't serve the JS file.

Comment: @Tkausl Oh. So What changes I need to do?

Comment: Create a handler for that js file too

Comment: Use webpack to load the script.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to serve files like html or js files you can create a static file server as folows:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    if(extname ==  '.js'){
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
        response.end(content, 'utf-8'); 
    });

}).listen(8000);
```